# OptimisticLockException caused by @Version annotated int not incrementing

Tags: java, sql, playframework-2.1, ebean

I started getting an OptimisticLockException thrown from my previously working Play application when I made the following modifications:

- I added a new field, hasStarted, to an entity:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class ExperimentInstance extends Model {
    @Version
    public int version;          
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public boolean hasStarted;
    ...
  ```

  defined in the database by:

  ```
  alter table experiment_instances add column has_started bit default 0;
  ```
- I update the new field inside of a TimerTask like so:

  ```
  final ExperimentInstance runningInstance = ExperimentInstance.findById(experimentInstanceId);
  new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      if (runningInstance != null) {
        runningInstance.hasStarted = true;
        runningInstance.save();
      }
    }
  }, lifetimeInMs);
  ```

I enabled transaction logs for my database and see the following two sql statements:

```
update experiment_instances set has_started=true, version=3 where id=3721 and version=2
```

and much later:

```
update experiment_instances set status='FINISHED', version=3 where id=3721 and version=2
```

It is clear the issue is that the @Version annotated field is not incrementing from 2 to 3 when the table is updated earlier; however, I have no idea where to start debugging this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding a "hasStarted()" method to a helper class in the private scope of the containing class like so:

```
public class HelperClass {
  private ExperimentInstance experimentInstance;

  public HelperClass(ExperimentInstance experimentInstance) {
    this.experimentInstance = experimentInstance;
  }

  public void hasStarted() {
    experimentInstance.hasStarted = Boolean.TRUE;
    experimentInstance.update();
  }
}

public class ContainingClass extends UntypedActor {
  ...
  private HelperClass helperClass = new HelperClass(experimentInstance);
  ...
  new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      helperClass.hasStarted();
    }
  }, lifetimeInMs);
  ...
```

I believe the issue was caused by the "final" keyword.